# ChartUtilities.getImageMap() not generating tooltip in JSF

Tags: jsf, jfreechart

I want tooltip to be generated on hover. The tooltip is being generated on Internet Explorer and Microsoft edge But not in Chrome and Firefox.
  I need to solution .
The code I tried is given below.

```
ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
ChartRenderingInfo chartRenderingInfo = new ChartRenderingInfo();
writer.write(ChartUtilities.getImageMap(uichart.getGenerateMap(),
                    chartRenderingInfo,
                    new StandardToolTipTagFragmentGenerator(),
                    new URLTagFragmentGenerator(uichart.getId())));
```

Comment: This is server-side code so if you're having issues with certain browsers this is probably not the root of the problem. Have you checked what the generated HTML looks like? And what library are those classes from?

Comment: @Makhiel I have looked into Html generated . It looks like:
  <area shape="poly" coords="673,254,678,248,683,254,683,254" title="(Total Paid , May-17) = 2,304.66" alt href="#" onclick="chartpaidTrendGraphClick('?series=Total+Paid+&category=May-17')">
<area shape="poly" coords="659,263,697,263,697,274,659,274,659,263,659,263" title="May-17" alt href="#" onclick="chartpaidTrendGraphClick('?category=May-17')">

Comment: And also I am using JFreeChart library

Comment: Well the titles are clearly there which means the tooltips are being generated. Why do you think this is a JSF/RichFaces problem? Try copying the map on a static page to see if there's something interfering with the mouseover.